# Ramda lib - javascript - data refactor/grouping

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have some raw country and start time data -- that is listed in the data like this

the lib I'm trying to use is ramda
https://jsfiddle.net/0kdcvahw/

```
  var data = [
    {
      "label": "Argentina",
      "isIncluded": true,
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time": Date.parse('2020-01-14T10:00:00Z'), "ending_time": Date.parse('2020-02-14T15:20:00Z')}
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Chile",
      "isIncluded": true,
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time": Date.parse('2020-01-14T10:00:00'), "ending_time": Date.parse('2020-05-20T03:24:00')}
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "United States of America",
      "isIncluded": true,
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time": Date.parse('2020-01-14T11:00:00Z'), "ending_time": Date.parse('2020-03-20T03:24:00')}
      ]
    }
  ];
```

and I want to reconfigure the list to be more like this

```
var data = [
    {
        label: 'Argentina, Chilie',
        value: 90,
    },
    {
        label: 'United States',
        value: 10,
    }
];
```

so basically - there are 3 countries --- 2 of them start on the same day and same start hour e.g. 10:00. - 1 starts on the same day but 11:00

---

code example - but needs to remove the last comma

```
var data = [
    {
      "label": "Argentina",
      "isIncluded": true,
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time": Date.parse('2020-01-14T10:00:00Z'), "ending_time": Date.parse('2020-02-14T15:20:00Z')}
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Chile",
      "isIncluded": false,
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time": Date.parse('2020-01-14T10:00:00'), "ending_time": Date.parse('2020-05-20T03:24:00')}
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "United States of America",
      "isIncluded": true,
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time": Date.parse('2020-01-14T11:00:00Z'), "ending_time": Date.parse('2020-03-20T03:24:00')}
      ]
    }
  ];


//console.log("data",data);
const groups = R.groupBy(x => x.times[0].starting_time, data);



const newData = Object.keys(groups).map(key => {
  return {
    label: groups[key].reduce((c, n) => `${c}${n.label}, `, ''),
    value: groups[key].length
  }
})

console.log('newData', newData)
```

Comment: Can you post your code, please? What problems are you having with your code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chunfengd/kqvcyp90/  - underscore version

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b3ptmey1/  - errors on grouping

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b3ptmey1/1/  -- kind of mocked the output -

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b3ptmey1/3/   -- the grouping - has got stuck on getting to a child prop

Comment: @Rob: you need to [edit] your question, we want posts to stand on their own without relying on third-party services.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0kdcvahw/   -- this is near complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Ramda approach:

```js
const transform = pipe (
  groupBy (path (['times', 0, 'starting_time'])),
  values,
  map (applySpec ({
    label: pipe (pluck ('label'), join (', ')),
    value: length
  }))
)

const data = [{"isIncluded": true, "label": "Argentina", "times": [{"ending_time": 1581693600000, "starting_time": 1578996000000, "text": ""}]}, {"isIncluded": false, "label": "Chile", "times": [{"ending_time": 1589945040000, "starting_time": 1578996000000, "text": ""}]}, {"isIncluded": true, "label": "United States of America", "times": [{"ending_time": 1584674640000, "starting_time": 1578999600000, "text": ""}]}]

console .log (transform (data))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {pipe, groupBy, path, values, map, applySpec, pluck, join, length} = R</script>
```

I made the assumption that the fact that some dates were missing the final `"Z"` was simply a typo.  If some are supposed to have it and the others aren't, you have some quite odd data, and it doesn't match the output you present, unless you happen to live in a place with that timezone.

After that, it's fairly straightforward code for Ramda.  `groupBy` takes a function that gives you a canonical key for the item.  Here we pass it the result of `path`.  `path` takes an array of Strings or integers and gives you back a function which will return the value at that path of the input object, or undefined if any of the nodes does not exist.  `groupBy (fn)` returns an object with an array at each of the canonical keys found, with the items in your input array partitioned into these arrays.

We call `values` on that result, which is little more than a reference to `Object.values`; it returns an array of arrays.

On each of those outer arrays (via `map`) we call `applySpec`, which takes a mapping of keys to functions, creating an object with those keys, whose values are the result of applying the corresponding function to your input value.  For `value`, we just return the `length` of the underlying array, and for `label` we pull the `label` entries from each object, and then join them with `", "`.

In answers here, I often show how modern JS makes certain Ramda functions less compelling.  While I could do so here by combining some simple ES6+-alternatives to `applySpec` and `values`, using simple lambdas for `length`, and replacing `pipe (pluck ('label'), join (', ')` with something like `arr => arr .map (item => item .label) .join (', ')`.  But I don't bother, since we'd still have to write a one-off equivalent to `groupBy`.  While that's not difficult, I think the code would be substantially longer than this.  And I don't see that it gains anything.  Of course I would do so if I wasn't already using Ramda in my project, but overall, this feels like a good time to use Ramda's simplifications.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with a general import of Ramda. - import * as R from 'ramda';  -- maybe the version I have in the libs is out of date

Comment: I see your fiddles pointing to a pretty old version of Ramda.  I tested with `0.26.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore has a group by function [here](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy).

It returns an object graph keyed by the property you supply as the group, and the value is the objects that match the supplied key

```
const groups = groupBy(data, item => item.times[0].starting_time)

console.log('groups', groups)

const newData = Object.keys(groups).map(key => {
  return {
    label: groups[key].reduce((c, n) => `${c}${n.label}, `, '')
  }
})

console.log('newData', newData)
```

Comment: Is there a version with ramda -

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chunfengd/kqvcyp90/  -- groupBy not defined

Comment: You have to import the library the add import {groupBy} from ‘underscore’ to your file

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b3ptmey1/ - trying to get ramda to work with the example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b3ptmey1/1/  -- kind of mocked the output -

Comment: I’ll have a look when I get home

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b3ptmey1/3/   -- the grouping - has got stuck on getting to a child prop

Comment: What child prop? Your grouping code works, I updated the assignment of newData to read from group2 and it printed out the data correctly.

Comment: no -- the child prop is times -- but really it needs to hit times.starting_time

Comment: isIncluded is the wrong prop of interest -- its times.starting_time instead

Comment: this doesn't work -- const groups2 = R.groupBy(R.prop('times[0]starting_time'))(data);

Comment: R.groupBy(x => x.times[0].starting_time, data);

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0kdcvahw/  - solved it - just need to clop the last ,

Comment: Do note that the version of Ramda used here, `0.22.1` is three years old.  There are several newer versions available.